# How to split a window with terminal below in vim with predefined size

Tags: vim

What I want is something like:

```
:below 10sp
```

Then open the terminal:

```
:terminal ++curwin
```

This two commands do exactly what I want but I don't know if it is the best way.

Comment: Maybe `:below terminal ++rows=10`?

Comment: BTW: For this kind of questions, you might want to join the [Vi and Vim Community](https://vi.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The `:terminal` command supports the `++rows={height}` option; cp. [`:help term++open`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#term%2B%2Bopen).

Answer (score 0):

Add `set splitbelow` to .vimrc.
Now, `:terminal` should split the screen with a terminal at the bottom.
For height, just use `++rows={height}` option.